# Why is the range of $D(x) = \frac{(5x+8)^2}{(x-15)^2}$ all non-negative numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$$D(x) = \frac{(5x+8)^2}{(x-15)^2}$$

The domain = all real numbers excluding $15$, because we cannot divide by $0$.

But, why is the range of this all real numbers greater than or equal to 0?

I've tried setting $D(x) = y$ and solving for $x$, but it's quite a tricky thing to solve for $x$. Any easier methods that you guys can suggest?

Comment: You can see this without any calculations if you observe that the form of both the numerator and the denominator are of the same form, i.e.,  $z^2$ for some real number $z$ - no matter what (real) $z$ you choose you can never get a negative $z^2$!

Comment: Can the square of a real number be negative? Consider any real number $a$. If $a$ were positive, obviously $a^2 $ is positive. If $a$ were negative, consider $a = -b$, where $b$ is positive. Now $a^2 = (-b)(-b) = + b^2$ and is again positive. ( As $b$ is positive). In any case the result is gonna be positive ($x  \ne 15$ makes the function undefined)

Answer (score 5):

It is clear that for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 15 \rbrace$, you have $D(x) \geq 0$. So the range is included in $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Moreover, $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 15^-} D(x) = +\infty \quad \text{ and } \quad D \left( \frac{-8}{5}\right) = 0$$ By continuity on $(-\infty, 15)$, the intermediate value theorem tells you that $\mathbb{R}_+$ is included in the range.

So the range of $D$ is $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is the case that:

$$\forall u \in \mathbb{R}: u^2 \geq 0$$

Let $u := \frac{5x+8}{x-15}$. Regardless of what $u$ is (it could be negative or positive or 0), its square is always going to be greater than or equal to 0.

Now, to prove that the range of the function under the given domain $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{15\}$ is $\mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{0\}$, you just need to show that every element of $\mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{0\}$ has a preimage that lies in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{15\}$. This is rather easy to do if you understand this definition.

If you don't, then I'd suggest learning about it first.

**Edit:**

So, the reason that I told you to learn about it first is just because it's easier to answer specific questions you may have about the definition, rather than just explaining it all over again. That was my rationale. However;

Let $r \in \mathbb{R}^+ \cap \{0\} = A$, since I'm lazy to type all that out every single time. Then, we need to find an $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{15\} = B$ so that $f(x) = r$. We have:

$$\frac{(5x+8)^2}{(x-15)^2} = r$$

$$\frac{5x+8}{x-15} = \sqrt{r}$$

$$5x+8 = (x-15)\sqrt{r}$$

$$5x+8 = \sqrt{r}x-15\sqrt{r}$$

$$(5-\sqrt{r})x = -8-15\sqrt{r}$$

$$x = \frac{8+15\sqrt{r}}{\sqrt{r}-5}$$

Note that we could have gone with $-\sqrt{r}$ right at the start and we could have gotten a different preimage. This is not a problem because we just need one preimage to show that the range is actually $A$.

Comment: I did not downvote, but strongly feel that this answer could be improved by pushing the OP at least one more step to constructing the preimage of given $y$ under $D$ instead of the last statement in the answer.

Comment: Would that be better? Thank you for the feedback :)

Comment: +1. thank you for taking the time to improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$D(x)=\frac{(5x+8)^2}{(x-15)^2}=(\frac{5x+8}{x-15})^2$$
Now we know from basic algebra that any number squared is greater than or equal to $0$, ie is positive (or non-negative, whichever term you prefer). As a result we see that as your function is $\frac{5x+8}{x-15}$ squared it can't be negative, ie its range is non-negative, as required.

Hope that helps :)

**Edit:**
We can also see that $D(x)$ takes *all* non-negative values by noting that $D(x)$ has a solution when it's set equal to zero (you should be able to work that out). Now, adding small values of $x$ will increase the value of $D(x)$ by a small amount, and so on ad anfinitum; so $D(x)$ contains all non-negative values, as required.

Comment: The question is not only to see that the range contains only non-negative numbers, but that the range is exactly the set of all non-negative numbers.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe , what else could it be if not exactly? Do you mean that I also need to show that it's impossible that some positive numbers may not be included?

Comment: Yes, you should prove that all the non-negative numbers are in the image of the function.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe ok. I'm not really sure why it's not evident from my answer. It's obvious that $D(x)$ can take the value of $0$, hence slightly larger values of $x$ will slightly increase $D(x)$, and so on ad infinitum?

Comment: What you wrote in your answer is much more obvious than what you added in your comments :) So this has to be added in the answer (with rigorous details, and not "it's obvious that...), yes !

Comment: @TheSilverDoe ok, will do :)

Answer (score -1):

Write
$$
D(x) = \frac{(5x+8)^2}{(x-15)^2} = \left(\frac{5x+8}{x-15}\right)^2 = f(x)^2
$$
The image of $f$ is $\mathbb R \setminus \{5\}$ because it is easy to solve $f(x)=a$ when $a\ne 5$. Therefore, image of $D$ is $\mathbb [0,\infty)$ except possibly for $25$. Since the image $f$ contains $-5$, the image of $D$ contains $(-5)^2=25$ and so is actually $[0,\infty)$.